# Trying to change data vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, vue.js

i am trying to override my data in the App.vue component. But everytime it takes the default data from the component if i try to overwrite it in my main.js. I am also making use of webpack

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="message">{{ message }}</div>
</template>

<script>
//import TopBar from './top-bar.vue'
export default {
    name: 'App',
    data () {
        return {
            message: 'hello world'
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: '<App/>',
    components: { App: App },
    data: {
      message: 'New text'
    }
})
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="dist/build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The App component and the parent component defined in `main.js` are two separate Vue instances with their own data property values which can have the same name. What are you trying to accomplish by overwriting App's `message` data property?

Comment: I am trying to make an default component wich i can give other values/methods in the main.js if necessary

Comment: I'd look into vue mixins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think youve got yourself confused about what is doing what. Your App.vue component and your main.js vue instance each have their OWN instance of the data property. If you want your main.js to be able to pass data into your component you need to expose a prop to do this in. If you want your app.vue component to be able to communicate with your main.js vue instance then you must raise an event and main.js must be listening for that event. I would highly suggest that you spend a day or two with the vuejs documentation. Its honestly some of the best software docs I have ever come across, and your problem is addressed pretty early on in the tutorial.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/